# How to attach screenshot to steps using AbstractTestNGCucumberTests?

Tags: cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

I want to attach screenshot to steps that is generated cucumber html report. My project use AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.

This is my takeScreenshot method:

```
public static void takeScreenshot(io.cucumber.core.api.Scenario scenario,
                                  WebDriver driver, File screenShotFile) {
    final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
    try {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(screenShotFile);

        os.write(screenshot);
        Log.debug("Successfully save screenshot");

        os.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.error("Exception : " + ex);
    }
}
```

I try to get Scenario by declaring anotation io.cucumber.java.Before
[image]

But Scenario is null

Please help me how to get io.cucumber.core.api.Scenario or another way to attach screenshot in steps for reporting

Comment: Add cucumber-picocontainer or any other DI library. Scenario will not be null

Comment: What have you added as a cucumber dependency ? Isn't it cucumber-java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. Cucumber hook @Before is just run in location that is defined in @CucumberOptions(glue=my-path). My Class TestSuiteMaster is in another path, so Scenario is null.

I created a class CucumberHook in directory stepDefinition and take screen shot method in hook @After, everything work great.

This is my CucumberHook class:

```
public class CucumberHook extends WebTestSuiteMaster {

    @After
    public void take_screenshot_after_finished_scenario(Scenario scenario) {
        String imageFileName = "Screen shot-" + scenario.getName() + "-"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm").format(new Date()) + ".png";
        File imageFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//screenshots//" + imageFileName);

        SeleniumWebHelper.takeScreenshot(scenario, driver, imageFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is SeleniumWebHelper ????? what is takeScreenshot?
You were asked how to do something you replied magicLib.doMeTheThing(); whithout mentioning even what lib

Comment: My problem is that scenario is null because Cucumber does not hook. And the detail of the screenshot method is in my question. My takeScreenshot method worked well with the project without Cucumber, you do not need to care it.